# Inserting values into a table with only 1 column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgres with exactly one column `id`. It has the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE braintree_events (
    id text PRIMARY KEY
);
```

When I try to insert a value using the insert syntax like so:

```
INSERT INTO braintree_events (id) VALUES ("event_id_1");
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:  column "event_id_1" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO
> braintree_events (id) VALUES ("event_id_1");

Why is my value being interpreted as a column name? This seems very weird, but I suppose having a table with only one column is also strange. I've tried fiddling with the insert statement and googling, but neither have provided any hints as to what exactly is going wrong here.

Comment: Use single quotes for a string.

Comment: double quotes are used to define an object within PostgreSQL, such as a table name or a column name. https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/postgresql/short-guides/quoting-rules#double-quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO braintree_events (id) VALUES ('event_id_1');
```